# proof or deproof linear equivalence of X, X is an amount.

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

[image: Question]

Again I am stuck at some proof.
I need to proof or deproof that for all linear equivalences:

R:(X,X)  is R = [image]

So far I think it is correct because we get symmetry and linearity, but I have troubles to proof it. Any help is upvoted immediately.

here the def of linearity:

[image: linearity]

symmetry here:

[image]

transitiv:

[image: transitiv]

reflexiv:

[image: transitiv]

linear equivalent is: transitiv, reflexiv, symmetric and linear

Comment: Please include definitions of "linear equivalence" and of $\nabla_{X,X}$

Comment: Your definition of reflexive is now same as transitive. (By the way what does "bzw" mean? Seems to be "equivalently stated") Also you still have not defined $\nabla_{X,X}$ in the post. Not only that, you did not define what $R(X,X)$ means, which appears at the start of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to be true.

You use symmetry and linearity according to the second formulations. Since $R$ is symmetric you have $R^{-1}\subseteq R$ and therefore $R = R^{-1}\cup R$ which by linearity will be equal to $\nabla_{X,X}$